# Wordpress PHP Call from Form with submit doesn't give a result

Tags: php, html, wordpress, forms

I'm Markus, I'm new to PHP and WordPress. I'm trying to build a form that the user could edit some data and then submit the data to the database. I used around 20-30 videos or sides to find a solution, but I don't understand why all the other tutorials work. Maybe you have an idea or see the mistake I couldn't. I use this function with a shortcode to display it on my WordPress side.

```
<?php

function example_form_plugin()
{
    ?>
    <html>
        <body>
            <h2>Contact us</h2>
            <?php
                if(isset($_POST['btn_save_teilnehmer'])){
                    echo 'Hello World';

                    /*global $wpdb;
                    $wpdb->insert(
                        $wpdb->prefix.'teilnehmer',
                        [
                            'teilnehmer_name'  => 'MARKUS'
                        ]
                    );*/
                }
            ?>
            <form methode="post">
                <input type="submit" name="btn_save_teilnehmer" value="Speichern"></input>
            </form>
            <br>
        </body>
    </html>
    <?php
}
```

Comment: Maybe try and uncommenting the database code so it actually gets executed? If you've done that, then please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/73448276/edit) the question and include a proper explanation of what actually happens. Please read [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). You should also [take the tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) that was recommended to you when you registered.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.